# Validating dynamically cloned forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an HTML form that gets validated using the jQuery validation plugin. It works fine, but the full extent of my project is to dynamically clone and append the form to the previous form. The dynamically cloned forms don't validate at all. How can I validate my dynamically created forms? My "#addOne" button generates the dynamically cloned forms.

*Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/37jhbb5g/5/*

**HTML**

```
<div class="article_properties">
  <form class="article_properties_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p style="display: inline">Page Number</p>
    <div style="background-color: #FF355E; padding: 5px; display: inline; margin-left: 5px">

      <p style="display: inline" class="pageNumber"></p>
    </div>
    <textarea style="display: none" class="inputNumber" name="pageNumber"></textarea>
    <p>Image</p>
    <input style="padding: 0px" type="file" name="image">
    <p>Subtitle</p>
    <input type="text" name="subtitle">

    <p>Text</p>
    <textarea name="text" rows="4"></textarea>
    <input id="properties_btn" type="submit" value="Submit/Update">
    <hr style="border: 1px dotted lightgray; margin-bottom: 50px">
  </form>

</div>
<!--End of article properties div-->
<div id="addOne">
  <p>+Add page</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".article_properties_form").validate({
  errorElement: 'div',
  rules: {
    image: {
      required: true,
      extension: "jpg,jpeg"
    },

    subtitle: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2,
      maxlength: 25
    },
    text: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 35,
      maxlength: 275
    }
  },

  messages: {
    image: {
      required: "This page needs an image",
      extension: "You're only allowed to upload jpg or png images."
    },

    subtitle: {
      required: "You have to provide a subtitle for this page!",
      minlength: "Your subtitle must be at least 2 characters long",
      maxlength: "Your subtitle must be less than 25 characters long"
    },
    text: {
      required: "Please enter text for this page",
      minlength: "Your text must be at least 35 characters long",
      maxlength: "Your text must be less than 275 characters long"
    },
  },

});


var numPages = 10;
$('.pageNumber').text(numPages);
$('.inputNumber').text(numPages);

$('#addOne').click(function() {

  numPages--;

  if (numPages == 1) {
    var articlePropsTemplate = $('.article_properties_form:last').clone();
    $('.article_properties').append(articlePropsTemplate);
    $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPages);
    $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPages);
    articlePropsTemplate[0].reset();
    $('.nextBtn').fadeIn("slow");
    $('#addOne').hide();
  } else {
    var articlePropsTemplate = $('.article_properties_form:last').clone();
    $('.article_properties').append(articlePropsTemplate);
    articlePropsTemplate[0].reset();
    $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPages);
    $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPages);
  }

});

$('body').on('submit', '.article_properties_form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($('.article_properties_form').valid()) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {

      }
    });
  } else {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 form elements in the first form. Then I think you will not need any jquery validations. And it will work in subsequent add on pages, too. Try this -

```
                            <p>Image</p>
                        <input style="padding: 0px" type="file" name="image"  accept="image/jpeg, image/png">
                        <p>Subtitle</p>
                        <input type="text" name="subtitle" pattern=".{2,25}" required title="2 to 25 characters" >

                        <p>Text</p>
                        <textarea name="text" rows="4"  maxlength="275" minlength="35" required></textarea>
```